# Spyder standalone - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, spyder

I am a relative newbie and have had to turn to Spyder standalone (no Anaconda).

I installed a package (multiple times at this point) in the Spyder console using "! pip install tableau_api_lib".  It says the "Requirement is already satisfied" and gives me the directory location of C:\Users\Xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages.

However, the package is not there!

I have watched the videos on Spyder's website, and have researched for hours with no luck.

Help!  Would appreciate any advice.